# How can I get the coordinates in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UITableView` where selecting a row trigger an `MPMoviePlayerController` with a video. I'm setting the size to 0, so it's invisible.

Now I'd like to make the hiding animation nicer, by having it converge on the cell that was selected.

I can't seem to find a way to get the coordinates of the selected row without doing some ridiculous thing such as making a transparent `UIView` on top of the `UITableView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow

CGRect yourRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath: [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
```

Comment: Great! I don't need the `indexPathForSelectedRow` as that is given as a parameter. But keep it in there for future reference.